# How to add contact string from one array to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cncontact, cncontactstore

I have a array which stores all the contacts from the phone. I have a UITableView in which i want to display all the contacts. I was having trouble displaying them in the table view o i created a new array, and used the below code to loop through the contacts array and fetch strings from it and store them in the new array (contactsNew)

```
for (CNContact *contact in contacts)
    {
        NSString *string = [formatter stringFromContact:contact];
        [contactsNew addObject:string];
        NSLog(@"contact = %@", string);
    }
```

The issue is all the contacts are displayed in the log, but i am still not able to display the contacts in table view.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [contactsNew count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView    
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]   
initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   
reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [contactsNew objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

I have checked the values of 'string' variable and the number and content being added to the contactsNew array, and everything looks fine.

Also can i use something else in place of:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [contactsNew objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

So that i can directly use the contacts array instead of creating a new array. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try [tableView reloadData] after for loop

Comment: @Tejas please reload tableview after some delay like code in my ans.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this

for (CNContact *contact in contacts)
{
        NSString *string = [formatter stringFromContact:contact];
        [contactsNew addObject:string];
        NSLog(@"contact = %@", string);
}
[tableview reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reload tableView after creating array so use [tableView reloadData] after for loop

```
for (CNContact *contact in contacts)
{
    NSString *string = [formatter stringFromContact:contact];
    [contactsNew addObject:string];
    NSLog(@"contact = %@", string);
}

[tableview reloadData]; //Add this line
```

Hope this will works.

Answer (score 1):

you need to reload tableview after some delay.
use like this

```
 for (CNContact *contact in contacts)
{
    NSString *string = [formatter stringFromContact:contact];
    [contactsNew addObject:string];
    NSLog(@"contact = %@", string);
}

//  add after Delay 0.5 if its not worked then 1.0

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [tableview reloadData];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to reload your table on main thread after you fetch the contacts... like:-  `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [_table reloadData]; });`

...and for your table view  write

`cell.textLabel.text = [contactsNew objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"keys";`

...provide the key here.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few points you need to check to resolve your issue :

- First thing you need to check is weather tableview methods called once after you added values to new Array ? If no than try reload table view after you are adding values to new array.
- If it calls correctly after adding values to new array try to `NSLog` values in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

Hope it will help you.